# How to combine Query Parameters in nextjs 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, navigation

```
const variantAction = (index: any, colorDef?: any) => {
    const safeIndex = index && index > -1 ? index : 0
    let colorIndex: number
    if (colorDef) {
      colorIndex = productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors.findIndex(
        (color: any) => color?.name === colorDef
      )
    } else {
      colorIndex = productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors.findIndex(
        (color: any) => color?.name === productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.defaultColor
      )
    }
    colorIndex = colorIndex && colorIndex > -1 ? colorIndex : 0

    setCurrentVariant(safeIndex)
    setImages(ImageMaker(productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors?.[colorIndex]))
    setSelectedColor(productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors?.[colorIndex]?.['@id'])
    setColors(productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors)
    setColorName(productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors?.[colorIndex]?.name)
    setSizes(productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors?.[colorIndex]?.sizes)
    setPersonalizationTexts(null)
    setError(false)
    checkWishlist(safeIndex)
    const s = productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.productId
    const c = productDetail?.variants?.[safeIndex]?.colors?.[colorIndex]?.name

    router.replace(`${pathname}?${createQueryString('c', c)}`)
    router.replace(`${pathname}?${createQueryString('s', s)}`)
  }
```

http://localhost:3000/campaign/33?xs=rw&s=gildan-18500
in above url i am able to see only  router.replace(`${pathname}?${createQueryString('s', s)}`) but i want to combin both route.replace statements and i want to show both in url

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.